# jQuery: Replace every char on page with an image

Tags: jquery

Need your help, maybe just tunnel-vision right now.

I just want to replace every occurrence of a special character with an image using jQuery. Can't be that hard, can it?

I found several questions and I've been through them, but maybe I'm just missing something.

In that case, I'll try to replace every dot `.` with an image from an external resource (which is accessible) regardless of it's container. It doesn't make a difference if it is in a `<p>` or `<div>` or even just standing alone.

```
$("body").html().replace('/\./g', "<img src='my external image link'>");
```

Shouldn't that just do it?

Comment: Yes and no, I don't think the DOM will get updated to the `<img>` element, it should only add them as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-assign the string you are building from the body's HTML.

Something like

```
let newHtml = $("body").html().replace(/\./g, "<img src='my external image link'>");
$('body').html(newHtml);
```

However, I'd be careful with replacing the '.'-character in the *entire* HTML, as it can be valid content of e.g. URLs in `a`nchors. But I'm sure you thought about that already :)

**Edit**: Fixed RegEx-syntax. You should leave away the single-quotes around the RegEx.

Comment: yeah, this is more for a special purpose. But you are absolutly right. Will accept soon I guess. Right now still struggling with a new error coming up which implies I'm doing ajax-requests... which I don't :/

Comment: u already solved it by yourself :) It was the `'` around the regexp